# How to get cell atIndex in UICollectionView with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am making Collection view programatically.
Here is the code in viewDidLoad func

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    collectionView!.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.containerView.addSubview(collectionView!)
```

And these are my collection view functions

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.buttonView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Action\(indexPath.row):"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Idea is I have a button in the cell, and when I press it the cell should change color, here is the action function

```
func Action0(sender: UIButton!) {
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell = collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

and this is collectionViewCell class,

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

var buttonView: UIButton!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    buttonView = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height*2/3)

    contentView.addSubview(buttonView)
}
```

}

The button and the action works but the cell doesn't change colour, i guess the problem is in this line

```
let cell = collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as! CollectionViewCell
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is the way to get the cell at a given indexPath:

```
let cell = collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

However, you also might want to try:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

**NOTE:**

Though the above may have worked, I want to encourage you to try a different implementation to achieve the same functionality. Your implementation would require you to have a separate Action# function for each CollectionViewCell, as well as create the indexPath manually in each of those methods, when you could potentially only have one!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.buttonView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

and the **function** for that one method would be something like:

```
func action(sender: UIButton!) {
    var point : CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:collectionView)
    var indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
    let cell = collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

**Updated action function for Swift 4.2**

```
@objc func action(sender: Any){
    print("tickedOffPressed !")
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        let point: CGPoint = button.convert(.zero, to: collectionView)
        if let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
            let cell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
}
```

Just a suggestion! Happy coding! :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

**In Swift 4 you can get the cell of CollectionView with:**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0);  
if let cell = myCollectionView .cellForItem(at: indexPath)  
{   
   // do stuff...  
}
```

Comment: You forgot to cast for CustomCell class.

Answer (score 5):

**Works on Swift 5.5 and iOS 15**

Adding on **Lakhdeep Singh** answer, if you want to have access to a specific cell's properties you need to cast it as the cell you want (ex. CustomCell). For instance, if this CustomCell has a **nameLabel**, you can access it like so:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0);  
if let customCell = myCollectionView .cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {   
    customCell.nameLabel.text = "some text"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try cell.selected and then change the color

Answer (score 0):

**if the cell is present in view then first condition will match otherwise else will call**

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0);  
    if let customCell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {   
        customCell.nameLabel.text = "some text"
    }else {
    if let customCell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        customCell.nameLabel.text = "some text"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 2 you can get the row with:

```
let point : CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:myTableView)
let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
```

Comment: this code is for UITableView, not UICollectionView like the asker wanted.