# IOS Swift Segue using data from selected Cell rather than the supporting array

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a string array of URLs, which drive the collection view cells shown on the master controller.  My custom cell has an UIImageView whose image property is loaded in the background via a function call as follows:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    loadImageInBackground(NSURL(string: self.fotosString[indexPath.row])!, target: cell.image!)
    return cell
}
```

My collectionViewController correctly displays all the images for the URLs I have in the array.

When I transition to the DetailView, I would like to use the data that was downloaded into the cell, rather than trigger a new download (even though the image would be in the cache) based on the URL string that is in the array.  So I am doing the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showImage" {
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        let indexPath = indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath
        let cell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        dvc.currentImage = cell.image.image
    }
}
```

However, `cell.image.image` returns `nil` and therefore my approach isn't working.

I could do this in a more conventional way by setting up a class for my photo images like:

```
urlStr: String
theImage: UIImage
```

But I am wondering why I'm getting the `nil`, and how I can access the image data directly from the cell.

Comment: Use `collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

Comment: could you paste the code for loadImageInBackground ? that would be helpful to identify the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get cell atIndex in UICollectionView with swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405726/how-to-get-cell-atindex-in-uicollectionview-with-swift)

Comment: @Caleb, possible.  But I am really looking for an explanation of why this approach is frowned upon.  I don't think it breaks the MVC pattern, since the model still contains the root information (URL in this case).  The image data is a function of the URL.  I can see, where there are a lot of URLs, that putting the image data into the model would make the application more efficient.

Comment: in strict MVC you can't ask the view for data so it is breaking MVC

Comment: But it's the controller that is deriving the data (actual image) from a URL.

Comment: Another problem is that the CollectionView only holds the currently reference cells.  Once an entry moves off the screen, its data is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do what you want to / are trying to do. You should pass the image URL from your data model and use that.

Your problem is that you're creating / reusing a cell rather than finding the current one by doing:

```
let cell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

where you should have:

```
let cell = self.collectionView!. cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct method.  However, I don't understand why I "shouldn't" be doing it this way.  (I've heard others, including my past Lecturer, say that but none have been able to actually explain the problems associated wtih this approach in a way that left me feeling "ok, that's why".

Comment: it's about role and responsibility, the data model holds the data, the view displays some data, so when you need to get data from someone it's the data model, not the view. problems with doing it the wrong way are harder, it could work fine, but you end up with a tangled mess where eventually you want to change something in the UI and you end up breaking the whole flow or storing data on a view when it isn't actually used by the view just so you can query it back later...

Comment: The actual data is the URL, while the image itself is retrieved by the controller and is thus derived data.  In the MVC pattern, can't the controller perform operations on the model's data in preparation for the sending it to the view?

Comment: Yes, the controller can manipulate the data before sending it to the view. MVVM is an extension of that where the view model does the manipulation.