# Getting nil whilst defining a cell in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have to get the cell at a specific index for my application. That's the way I do it:

```swift
        let cell1 = gamePad.cellForItem(at: [0, actualBund])
        let cell2 = gamePad.cellForItem(at: [0, actualBund + 1])
        let cell3 = gamePad.cellForItem(at: [0, actualBund + 2])
        let cell4 = gamePad.cellForItem(at: [0, actualBund + 3])
```

When I now want to assign a backgroundColor to the cell, that doesn't work, because the cell constants are nil.

What can be done about this problem?

Comment: Create the indexPath, [get the cell for indexpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405726/how-to-get-cell-atindex-in-uicollectionview-with-swift), play around.

Comment: This is not *defining* a cell. This is not an `IndexPath` you're passing in there.

Comment: You can only get a visible cell. But why do you need the cell? You should only be accessing your data model.

Comment: Read the documentation of `cellForItem(at:)`. Also that's strange because you don't seem to create an `IndexPath`.

Comment: @Larme actualBund is of type Int

Comment: @Larme so it is an indexPath or am I wrong?

Comment: You don't have a warning? I don't know that nomenclature for init an IndexPath. I'd do `IndexPath(item: actualBund, section: 0)`, cf. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath/1779555-init Also, as said, `cellForItem(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible.

Comment: and what is meant with "not visible"?

Comment: Not visible on screen. Imagine you open `Contacts.app`. If you have more contacts than you can display without scrolling, the other one are not visible.